# install gem in local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

> I am using pry gem for debugging my rails application. So I have
>   specified it in my Gemfile and using it. But I dont need to push the
>   Gemfile with pry gem specified. So everytime I need to revert it to
>   original Gemfile and push it to remote repo.
>
> I was wondering is there any way where I can install pry gem in my
>   local machine and use it in my rails app globally so that I dont have
>   to specify that gem in Gemfile.??

I tried to do

```
gem install pry
```

But when I use binding.pry in my rails controller, it says

```
undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x0000000619398>
```

Answer (score 0):

With bundler you can create groups according to your environments.
You can intall your gem only for the development group.
Put the line below in your gemfile.

```
gem 'pry', :group => :development
```

Comment: @
Nitin Satish Salunke I agree that we can create groups per environment. But this does not solve my problem since I will be pushing the Gemfile to remote repo and I will have to revert it. So is there any way without specifying it in Gemfile.

Comment: @rubyist I guess there is no such option to achieve to what you want.
Only the gems that you specify in your gemfile are included in your environment.